# React Context values not referenced correctly in dynamic element functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I created a Context and hook to be able to see if areas of the application has been changed, and validate actions based on the current state in context.

Its called `DirtyContext` and the Implementation is used as follows:

```js
const {isDirty, setDirtyContextFor} = useDirtyContext();
```

`setDirtyContextFor(key)` - Ads a key to a list, to mark something as dirty.

`isDirty` - Reports the current state of the application based on a memoized value that updates everytime something is removed or added to the list of keys.

I have a list of objects, that helps me create a set of dynamic elements on the page.

```js
  const thisFunctionWillLooseContextReference = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log('Context Value - IsDirty: ', isDirty)
  };

  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState(() => {
    return [{onClick: thisFunctionWillLooseContextReference}]
  });
```

This is tied together in the UI using the following:

```js
  const renderButtons = () => {
   return buttons.map((btn, index) => (
     <button onClick={btn.onClick}>Button-{index}</button>
   ));
  }
```

Even if the context value `isDirty` is set to `true`, the function passed to the button, always just reports the initial value of `isDirty`.

Would appreciate any help on why this is happening, and how i can get the expected results (which is the correct/current value of `isDirty`)

Codepen - Have a look at the console when clicking the buttons:
(Code and implementation details are reduced to the smallest reproducable state)

```js
const { useState, useMemo } = React;


const DirtyContext = React.createContext();

const DirtyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  
    const [dirtyList, setDirtyList] = useState(new Set());
    const isDirty = useMemo(() => {
        return dirtyList.size > 0;
    }, [dirtyList]);

    function setDirtyStateFor(componentName) {
        const newDirtyList = new Set(dirtyList);
        newDirtyList.add(componentName);
        setDirtyList(newDirtyList);
    }


    return (<DirtyContext.Provider value={{
        setDirtyStateFor,
        isDirty,
    }}>
        {children}
    </DirtyContext.Provider>);
};

const useDirtyContext = () => React.useContext(DirtyContext);

const MyDirtyLittleApp = () => {
  const {isDirty, setDirtyStateFor} = useDirtyContext();
  const [input, setValue] = useState("");
  
  const thisFunctionWillLooseContextReference = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log('Context Value - IsDirty: ', isDirty)
  };
  
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState(() => {
    return [{onClick: thisFunctionWillLooseContextReference}]
  });
  
  
  function handleInput(event) {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    setDirtyStateFor('MyDirtyLittleApp');
  }
  
  function updateInput(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Am i dirty ?', isDirty)
  }
  
  const renderButtons = () => {
   return buttons.map((btn, index) => (
     <button class="button is-dark" data-reactstuff={isDirty} onClick={btn.onClick}>btn {index}</button>
   ));
  }
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <h1>{isDirty ? 'I`m Dirty': 'I`m Clean'}</h1>
      <form className="form">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="name-1">Update DirtyContext</label>
            <div class="control">
              <input type="text" value={input} name="name-1" onChange={handleInput} class="input"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <button onClick={updateInput} class="button is-dark">Save</button>
              {renderButtons()}
            </div>
            <control>
              <h5>Check console for results when clicking on the buttons</h5>
            </control>
          </div>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <DirtyContextProvider>
    <div className="box">
        <MyDirtyLittleApp /> 
    </div>
      </DirtyContextProvider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/Cnordbo/pen/zYqwVRL